# Remote task by using Task Scheduler Manager wrapper

Tags: task, scheduler

Currently I am trying to create a task in remote machine through TaskService class. The remote machine is connected through workgroup. But I am not able to create task in remote machine. I am getting following exception.

System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
Message=Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I am trying to create it in following way.

```
TaskService ts = new TaskService("COMPUTERNAME", "remoteUserAcctName", "DOMAINNAME", "remoteUserPassword");
```

I am trying to create task in remote computer running Windows 7 from a computer running Windows 7. Is it possible? Because as per this link, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766266.aspx , one can connect to remote computers running Windows Server® 2008, Windows Vista®, Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, or Windows 2000.

Also I tried from Task Scheduler menu 'Action | Connect to Another Computer', http://screencast.com/t/wIDbDcdhOE , I got error 'You do not have permission to access this computer'.

Details here, https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/discussions/570851.

Comment: This is working fine in domain environment. Earlier I tried in work group environment.

Answer (score 0):

The following is working fine in domain environment. Earlier I tried in work group environment.

```
TaskService ts = new TaskService("COMPUTERNAME", "remoteUserAcctName", "DOMAINNAME", "remoteUserPassword");
```

Comment: If you would like create task in remote machine, this will not work.

Comment: You ever figure anything out?  I'm able to create a task, but when I try to run it, it does nothing.

Comment: I was not able to create the task. Details here, https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/discussions/570851